# How can I use config as default in another config in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, config

Application.yml

```
serverHost: http://localhost:8084
serverPort: 8080
oidc.serverRedirect: ${server-host}
oidc.url: ${serverHost}${serverPort}
```

Config class:

```
@Data
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("oidc")
public class HostConfig {

    private String serverRedirect;
    private String url;

}
```

My goal is to assign serverHost and serverPort value as default in oidc.serverRedirect and oidc.serverPort through @Value.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do it.

```
@Component
public class Hostconfig {
    
    @Value("oidc.serverRedirect")
    private String serverRedirect;
    
    @Value("oidc.url")
    private String url;

    public void getValue(){
        System.out.println("1 " + serverRedirect);
        System.out.println("2 " + url);
    }
}
```

Or the other way.. use *prefix=oidc*, and the name of the java attribute should match with the properties file attributes.

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "oidc") 
public class Myconfiguration {
    
    private String serverRedirect;
    private String url;
    
    public String getServerRedirect() {
        return serverRedirect;
    }
    public void setServerRedirect(String serverRedirect) {
        this.serverRedirect = serverRedirect;
    }
    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }
    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

The above can be executed using -

```
@Component
public class Simple implements InitializingBean{

    @Autowired
    Hostconfig config;
    
    @Autowired
    Myconfiguration c;
    
    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        config.getValue();
        
        System.out.println("1 " + c.getServerRedirect());
        System.out.println("2 " + c.getUrl());
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah i know that the way to inject config into field. But i also need to add serverHost as default which is another config in yml. Therefore i not need to mention oidc.serverRedirect in application.yml if the value is same. I just want to clean up my application.yml.

Comment: Okay, something like this?
@Value("#{systemProperties['oidc.serverRedirect'] ?: 'http://localhost:8084'}")
private String serverRedirect;

Comment: Basically i want something list this but not sure will it work or not @Value("oidc.serverRedirect?:#{systemProperties['serverHost']")
private String serverRedirect;